# Access OwnerTableView ParentItem

Tags: javascript, vb.net

It is my **Vb.net** code it works perfectly.

```
Protected Sub ChkTaxCheckedChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim chkTax As CheckBox
        Dim gv1 As GridDataItem
        chkTax = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
        gv1 = DirectCast(chkTax.NamingContainer, GridDataItem)

        Dim txtAmount1 As Label = CType(gv1.OwnerTableView.ParentItem.FindControl("lblItemAmount"), Label)
End Sub
```

But now I want to achieve the same functionality in clientside using **JavaScript**.
Like :

```
function ChkTaxCheckedChanged1(sender, args) {
    var check = sender.get_parent()..??????
}
```

Any one know how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script>
            function handleClick(sender,args) {
                //i have used jquery so do not forgot add jquery reference
                var checkboxid = sender.get_id();
                var parentRow = checkboxid.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()[0].previousSibling;
                $(parentRow).find('span').html('Your text comes here');
            }
        </script>
```